# Завершить программу считывания скорости двигателя гироскопом, когда скорость двигателя будет равна ~ 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, инспекция-кода

Решил задачу следующим способом: программа считывает значение первые несколько секунд. Пока двигатель разгоняться, проверка значения скорости не работает. Через пару секунд после разгона срабатывает таймер, который изменяет флаг переменной TimeEND и после это уже начинает работу функция которая проверяет равна ли скорость нулю. Если больше нуля, то программа продолжает работать, а если равна нулю, следовательно двигатель остановился и можно прекращать работу программы.

Как мне кажется программа слишком запутана и нерациональна. Как можно её упростить и сделать более pythonic?

```
import random
import time
from threading import Timer

m = 0  # Число при котором цикл завершится
TimeEND = False  # Флаг начального времени для разгона двигателя
MotorStop = False  # Флаг остановки двигателя
StartTime = time.time()  # Время запуска


def randoms(min, max):
    x = random.randint(min, max)
    return x


def foo(x):
    global MotorStop
    if x == m:
        MotorStop = True
    return MotorStop


def timeout_handler():  # Функция остановки цикла
    global TimeEND
    StepTime = time.time()  # Время окончания 
    TotalTime = StepTime - StartTime  # Вычисляем затраченное время
    print("Время, затраченное на выполнение данного кода = ", TotalTime)
    TimeEND = True  # Меняем флаг времени на разгон

try:
    timer = Timer(2.05, timeout_handler)  # Инициализация таймера
    timer.start()  # Запуск таймера
    while MotorStop == False:  # Проверяем флаг остановки двигателя
        x = randoms(0, 10)  # Эмуляция данных гироскопа
        print(x)
        if TimeEND:  # Если начальное время на разгон истекло, начинается проверка условия скорости
            MotorStop = foo(x)

finally:
    StepTime = time.time() 
    TotalTime = StepTime - StartTime  
    print(
        f"Завершение работы. Двигатель Остановился через {TotalTime} секунды")
```

Comment: При моделировании каких-то объектов реального мира удобно использовать классы. При тестировании используете тестовый класс, при взаимодействии с реальным объектом меняете тестовый класс на класс со всеми теми же методами (таким же интерфейсом), который берет данные с реальных датчиков.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Непонятно для чего вы используете `global` в функции `foo`, если значение все равно отдаете через `return`

```
def foo(x):
    MotorStop = False
    if x == m:
        MotorStop = True
    return MotorStop
```

Однако тогда лучше сделать так:

```
def foo(x):
    return x == m
```

Тогда для чего выносить это в отдельную функцию ?:

```
try:
    timer = Timer(2.05, timeout_handler)  # Инициализация таймера
    timer.start()  # Запуск таймера
    while MotorStop == False:  # Проверяем флаг остановки двигателя
        x = randoms(0, 10)  # Эмуляция данных гироскопа
        print(x)
        if TimeEND:  # Если начальное время на разгон истекло, начинается проверка условия скорости
            MotorStop = x==m
...
```

2. Можно сделать так:

```
Timer(2.05, timeout_handler).start()
```

вместо ваших

```
timer = Timer(2.05, timeout_handler)  # Инициализация таймера
timer.start()  # Запуск таймера
```

3. Цикл `while` можно сделать таким, избавившись от переменной `MotorStop`:

```
while True:  # Проверяем флаг остановки двигателя
    x = randoms(0, 10)  # Эмуляция данных гироскопа
    print(x)
    if TimeEND and x==m:
        break
```

4. Пожалуй, финал: названия переменных лучше делать "нормальными". `m` - что за переменная такая. Лучше - `stop_speed`

Comment: Если не буду использовать global, то будет следующая ошибка: "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'MotorStop' referenced before assignment"

Comment: @leach исправил

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что если использовать MotorStop = x==m, то функция foo вообще не нужна?

Comment: @leach да, именно

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Вышло гораздо проще и лаконичнее.

Comment: @leach я не трогал функцию `randoms`, т.к. думаю, что это лишь "заглушка" и в  действительности там проходят более сложные процессы. но если это не так, то она тоже не нужна, по сути.

Comment: Да, Вы совершенно правы. Функция randoms только для того, чтобы эмулировать данные гироскопа.